# How does Origen handle tests pre-pattern and pre-flow?

Tags: origen-sdk

Prior to creating a test program flow with tests that contain patterns there is what is commonly referred to as the 'test list'.  This test list is commonly stored in Excel or as Jira tickets, and it determines what is run through simulation or emulation prior to first silicon.  [Given all of the test pattern generation capabilities of Origen](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/pattern/creating/), users must deal with this test list in some manner. I don't see any IP or top level $dut modeling for tests that would yield an API like this:

```
$dut.ddr.has_tests? # => true
$dut.ddr.tests      # => [:ddr4_2133_dataeye, :ddr4_1867_dataeye]
```

Anyone who is creating patterns with Origen, can you explain how Origen interacts with your 'test list'?

thx

Answer (score 0):

We don't tend to handle that in the model, see the comments about lists here: http://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/pattern/running/?highlight=list

Comment: I wonder if there is value though as keeping the tests in the $dut and IP models would allow there to be a chain of custody regarding how well the tests performed across products.  Would a PR be accepted for a generic Test class that would be part of the SubBlock by default?  The tests hash for each IP could drive test program flow iteration and create the actual pattern lists needed for generation of patterns.

Comment: I can see value in doing that, there has definitely been occasions where we could really have used programming logic to manipulate the lists for a specific product build case, and we had to come up with a hacky solution. Also how an IP plugin can share a list with a top-level application is hacky at best right now, if not downright un-supported.

Comment: @rchitect-of-info, please consider using the RFC process to define and refine a proposal up front, this is an ideal candidate for that - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/rfcs

Comment: OK will transfer it to the rfcs process.